# OAuth state param for CSRF - a potential spot for DDOS?

Tags: oauth-2.0, csrf, ddos

The first step for OAUTH applications is to request the identity of the Auth provider (such as GitHub, Facebook etc). For this request, it is expected to create an unguessable random string. It is used to protect against cross-site request forgery attacks (see [github documentation](https://developer.github.com/apps/building-oauth-apps/authorizing-oauth-apps/#web-application-flow)). This string is later checked as it is sent back by the provider.

This means that I have to store such string on my backend every time when the provider's URL is requested (i.e. on the login page).

This can lead to a DDOS attach by simply calling my login page over and over: the new CSRF string will be generated and stored all over again.

First: is my logic correct, maybe I am missing something?

Second: is there any better way to prevent this misbehavior? I can use timed cache, where CSRF tokens expire, but still not good enough.